# Populate fragment listview from async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to populate the listview from the loadListTask. You will see at the end of script, where it should happen. How to do that ?
I tried several methods, but always the same result, a crash.

Main activity here and the async task at the end :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LoadListTask myLoadListTask = new LoadListTask();
    myLoadListTask.execute();


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new SectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public SectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem;
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        SimpleAdapter mSchedule;
        listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ListView maListViewPerso = new ListView(getActivity());

         mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (getActivity(), listItem, R.layout.affichageitem,
               new String[] {"img", "titre", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.titre, R.id.description});
         maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);




        switch (getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        case 1:

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("titre", "Excel");
            map.put("description", Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.devoir));
            listItem.add(map);

        case 2:
            //To do
        case 3:
            //To do
        }

        return maListViewPerso;
    }
}


// I NEED TO POPULATE FROM HERE
private class LoadListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        return 0;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (result == 0) {
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: What's the logcat say when it crashes?

Comment: Simply pass a reference of your `SectionFragment` to your `LoadListTask`, then create and set the adapter on `onPostExecute()`. @codeMagic: there's nothing to see in the logcat because he still doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: I know he doesn't have anything in there now but it sounded like he had tried something and it crashed so I thought he may have had something close but took it out

Comment: yes CodeMagic is right. I don't know how to add listItems from the Async Task.

Comment: If I was right then include what you tried to display the list and the logcat when it crashed. If you simply don't know how to do it at all then start with what @m0skit0 suggested and go from there

Comment: I already told you what to do in my comment. Maybe you should try. @codeMagic: he doesn't have any Exception because his AsyncTask does **nothing**.

Comment: Oh didn't see your comment. I'll try and tell you the result. Tks

Comment: @m0skit0 I understand that. He said my comment was right which means that he had something in there at some point but it wasn't working and so he took it out which means he would have had something when it crashed. But I told him to try what you said since he currently has nothing in there ;)

Comment: Note that you should be using a Loader. It's much more natural to use them with fragments, and simplifies saving the state between orientation changes.

Comment: @m0skit0, I didn't manage to "pass a reference of your SectionFragment to your LoadListTask" :-(

Comment: I finally did it with a loader, like dmon suggested it.. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a reference to listItem and to maListViewPerso to use them in onPostExecute, you can do it by declaring them as members of your class.

After doing that,you have to create your adapter. [(adapter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) For simple data structures you can use one of the Android's pre-defined, such as [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) or [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) but I suppose that what you want to do is to create a list which iterates through the ArrayList and then into the items of the map. To do so you have to implement your own adapter, extending BaseAdapter. Implementing [getView(int pos)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) you have to return the item in the position *pos* and with [getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount%28%29) the ListView would know how many items your list have.

Comment: In fact he only needs a reference to the List's adapter.

Comment: I added these two references and now it works like a charm. Thanks Terendul ! (and all other people who joined this thread)